# Open source updated blockchain explorer for altcoin

Tags: altcoin, litecoin, blockexplorer, open-source

Is there updated blockchain explorer available to work with altcoin?

I configured the most popular blockhain explorer: [iquidus explorer](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer) but the transactions display table are limited on display, can't show or paginate all transactions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
[insite api](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api). You can customize the code for any altcoins. They provide UI and API for explorer services